# how to select data from cell and copy to range until other data found open office calc

Tags: excel, cells, openoffice-calc

There is the issue

[image]

I wonder if there is a way like if there is date(or text,e.g.) on B1 cell then copy B1 data to the range A2-A19, until the next cell with data (B20) and so goes on. Because on much data cannot be done by hand.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  The picture does not seem to agree with your description.  Cells A1 and A20 are empty, and cells B1 and B20 have dates in them.  Perhaps you would like data from B2:B19 copied to A2:A19?  It would be more clear if you show an image of the desired result.

Comment: That's correct. I have different data on my work and when i tried to explain with example what i want to achieve i messed up a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "date" values in column B are actually text, then enter into A1:

```
=IF(ISERROR(AND(FIND("/";B1)=3;FIND("/";B1;4)=6));OFFSET(A$1;ROW()-2;0);B1)
```

This tests for cell B1 having a "/" character at the third and sixth positions in the string.

If the "date" values are in column B are actually entered into the spreadsheet as dates, then enter into A1:

```
=IF(YEAR(B1)<1950;OFFSET(A$1;ROW()-2;0);B1)
```

This tests for the integer value of B1 (in the case of a date, this value is the number of days since December 31, 1899) falling in a year earlier than 1950.  You may have to adjust 1950 to a different year depending on the details of your data.

In either case, if the test fails then the value from the previous row of column A is displayed (offsetting cell A1 by the current row minus two: for example on row 3, A1 will be offset by 3-2= **1** and A1 offset by 1 is A2).

If the test succeeds then the value from the corresponding row in column B is displayed.

The $ in the `A$1` will keep that value constant when the formula is copy-pasted, so the offset calculation will work correctly.  All the other values will adjust appropriately when you copy-paste down the row.

Comment: I actually didn't want to take the date but any data will be in case, date,text,and so goes on. Your first idea was what i want, i edited it a bit '=IF(ISERROR(FIND("/00";B2));OFFSET(A$1;ROW()-2;0);B2)' and that is what works exactly as i want, so i will change the /00 at anything i want at any case. The 'OFFSET(A$1;ROW()-2;0);B2)' was the magic in my issue. Thank you.